# How do you define a GraphQL host type using a code-first field resolver?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, code-first, resolver

I am using NestJS with TypeORM to connect with a MongoDB server running on a docker image. I am getting this error when trying to start the application:

```
type-metadata.storage.js:263
            throw new cannot_determine_host_type_error_1.CannotDetermineHostTypeError(item.schemaName, objectTypeRef === null || objectTypeRef === void 0 ? void 0 : objectTypeRef.name);
                  ^
Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL host type  (CreateClassInput?) for the "students" field. Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator (e.g., @ObjectType()).
    at TypeMetadataStorageHost.compileExternalFieldResolverMetadata
```

The field resolver is for a field named `students`. `Students` is an array of `StudentOutput` objects. The parent of `students` is defined in a GraphQL `@ObjectType()` class named `ClassOutput`:

```
@ObjectType()
export class ClassOutput extends PartialType(UpdateClassInput) {
  @IsUUID('4', { each: true })
  @Field(() => String)
  class_id: string;

  @Field(() => [StudentOutput], { defaultValue: [] })
  students: StudentOutput[];
```

The resolver properly lists `ClassOutput` as the parent GraphQL type for the `students` field.

```
@ResolveField()
  students(@Parent() classGQLObject: ClassOutput): Promise<StudentOutput[]> {
    return this.studentsService.findStudentsByIDArray(classGQLObject);
  }
```

Changing the decorator of `ClassOutput` from `@ObjectType()` to `@InputType()` did not resolve the error. This is how the `students field is defined in the TypeORM entity class:

```
@Entity('classes')
export class ClassesEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: ObjectID;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  class_id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'array', default: [] })
  students: StudentOutput[];
```

Why is GraphQL unable to find the parent type of `students` when the parent type is defined in the resolver function thru `students(@Parent() classGQLObject: ClassOutput)`, the decorated GraphQL class`ClassOutput`, and the entity?

Comment: Hey, buddy, have you solved the issue? what's the solution?

Comment: None yet. I changed the app and database so that I did not need a subscriber. That is not  a "solution."